# GNOME Control Center Issue

Tags: gnome, settings, gnome-control-center

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and since then I am not able to open the gnome settings app. The app launches and disappears somewhere in the right corner of the screen. I can see it launching and also when I minimize it but not able to to locate where it launches.

Comment: What do you get as output when you run it in the terminal? (`gnome-control-center`)

Answer (score 0):

The default display driver (possibly X.Org X Server driver) you perhaps installed might be giving you problems and changing to a proprietary one might help you. In [Software & Updates] go to the [Additional Drivers] tab and look to use an 'alternative' or lower versioned and stable but proprietary driver like the Nvidia ones if suggested. After the change is applied, remember to restart the system and you might be able to see the 'Settings' aka Gnome Control Center appearing in your desktop area when it is launched.

If the above action still does not work for you, the 'Settings' window actually can be dragged onto the main desktop screen area. You just need to move the cursor to the top right corner past the right edge of the visible screen to pull it over. It is hiding there for some reason perhaps due to settings in the installed display driver.